# Regex for validating name

Tags: regex, windows-phone-7

Any one please tell me the regex expression for allowing alphabet as first letter  and alphabets,digits,.(dot),-(hyphen) as remaining letters with minimum of 2 letters and maximum of 15 letters.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: You'll get many more answers if you post what you've tried so far. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this works for you:

```
^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9]|\.|-){1,14}$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with ASCII:

```
^[A-Za-z][-\w.]{1,14}$
```